Implement functionality to sort the Outlook inbox by date, from the oldest to the newest emails
Is there any way to add email sorting functionality in outlook addin by date, from the oldest to the newest emails through frontend.
In case of any possibility kindly suggest me how can I do this, Thanks.

What exactly are you trying to do? Change the folder sort order as shown by Outlook to the end-user? Loop through a folder messages in a particular order?

I want to change order of my inbox emails. Is it possible?

Not in a JS addin. In OOM (COM based), you can use Explorer.CurrentView / TableView.SortFields.
